# iPad 2 performance issue Adobe Air

Tags: actionscript-3, ipad, air, adobe

I am developing an application with high resolution illustrations on Flash for the iPad. In some cases I need to move these big images from one side of the screen to another (simple move animation). When I run my app on iPad 4 the animations are smooth. When I run the same app on iPad 2, the images have really great difficulty moving and the app is really laggy.

My current Adobe Air options are:
Render mode: GPU
Resolution: High
Stage Quality: High

Is there a way to adapt these settings to different iPad devices? Or do you have any other suggestions?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please show your code for moving your images.

Comment: What framerate are you using? The default 24fps is generally too low for smooth animations on low resolution devices. Try bumping it to 30, 48 and 60 and seeing if it improves at all (though make sure to test the entire app. The higher the framerate, the less time each frame has to render and the more likely you are to drop frames)

Comment: I just move the images' x position through a timer. The timer is set like this: timer = new Timer(1,0);

Answer (score 0):

If, by 'simple move animation', you mean moving from keyframe to keyframe across many frames, that could be your problem with slower processors. Move your images programatically by changing their 'x' or 'y' values inside an ENTER_FRAME loop. Then end the loop when the image has got to where you want it.

If you are already doing something like this, please show us your code.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to adapt these settings to different iPad devices? Or
>   do you have any other suggestions?

Transformations on large resolution images on the display list is very expensive even with render mode set to gpu. I've been dealing with this exact issue frequently, and the best results I've had are with hardware accelerated libraries and frameworks, particularly with Starling. I would recommend integrating a basic starling setup, and adding your images to a `QuadBatch`, then you can translate the QuadBatch around. This will take advantage of the GPU instead of the CPU and you should see much better performance. Here's a very basic example of what that would look like:

First after including the library, setup staring (usually in your main class):

```
private var _starling:Starling = new Starling( myClass, stage );
_starling.start();
```

This launches starling, the passed "myClass" will get instantiated by starling. So in your myClass you would do something like this:

```
//class level variable of type QuadBatch
private var _quadBatch:QuadBatch;

public function myClass() {
    //add event listener for added to stage
    addEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded );
}

private function onAdded( e:Event ):void {
    removeEventListener( Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, onAdded );
    _quadBatch = new QuadBatch();
    addChild( _quadBatch );    //add quadbatch to the stage3d display list
    addImageToQuad();
}

private function addImageToQuad():void {
    //first you create a starling texture from your bitmap
    var texture:Texture = Texture.fromBitmap( myBitmapImage );

    //add it to the quad as a starling Image type
    var image:Image = new Image( texture );
    _quadBatch.addImage( image );
}
```

At this point you can do all your normal translations using the `_quadBatch` like you would any other display object and it should perform much smoother. This is a very basic implementation, but if you are working with high resolution images I highly recommend you try this out as you will not get better performance with the default display list rendering. Lastly you would set the renderMode to "direct" (although I believe this happens automatically when using Starling/Stage3D anyway).